# Setting up mysql on mac

Tags: mysql, database, installation, database-administration

I have successfully installed mysql on my mac, and now on the command-line I can type `which mysql` and the mac replies back the expected path.

I would like to get started with the tutorial [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/tutorial.html).  But according to that tutorial, I need to some additional set up before starting that tutorial.  The document refers me to the [server administration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-administration.html) chapter, but this doesn't show my how to perform the remaining setup... it's more like a reference, so I don't know where to get started.

Is there any good document online to show me how to start administering my mysql database so that I can work through the tutorial?

---

update: If it's imporant, typing `mysql -u root` at the command line replies this error: `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`

---

In case anyone is interested, [this](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tutorials/sql/index.php3) is the best mysql tutorial that I've found on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a mac person, but the error means that mysql isn't running. Have you tried to start it?

**Update**: There is a document here that has simple instructions for installing mysql.

http://doc.us.extensis.com/Installing-MySQL-on-OSX.pdf

It said the command to start the server is `sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start`

I also don't suggest the tutorial on the mysql site, because it can be unclear at times. I am sure there are good one specifically for a mac.

Also, if you are running a web server with PHP, phpMyAdmin makes it easy to visually administer your database. I saw there is a mac version here: http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/8179/phpmyadmin.

Comment: Starting mysql... do tell.  (you see I'm very new to all of this)

Comment: mysql is a program that runs in the background & connects to your database when programs or scripts try to access it. Let me look at the tutorial you are using & I will see if I can suggest anything.

Comment: Are you using Mac OS X?

Comment: yes I am using a Mac OS X

Comment: Good information, all.  It turns out that I needed to change the owner and group (in the linux sense) of some of the mysql components, per this document (near the bottom): http://developer.apple.com/internet/opensource/osdb.html .  Based on what you said, I'll work through the mysql tutorial long enough to see that things work, and then I'll try to find something better.

Comment: I hope you get it working.

Answer (score 1):

safe_mysqld & 
will start mysql from the directory where is installed.
the first time you start it you will have to initialize the mysql tables - not
sure if this applies to mac.

as an alternative I use MAMP which is the same as LAMP but for mac - has a widget so
you can control servers etc.